# how to group the data having similar values in php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, group-by, group-concat

I have a table in the database named 'transactions'. I want to list out the values from this table. The result should be displayed in HTML table format. The rows in the resulted table should be grouped as per the amount.There is a column named 'amount' in the 'transactions' table.

Here is my code:

```
$s1 = DB::table('transactions')
        ->select(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(selected_seats SEPARATOR '') as selected_seats"),'userid','amount','show_id')
        ->where("show_id","=",$s)  
        ->groupBy('userid')
        ->groupBy('amount')
        ->orderBy('userid','ASC')
        ->orderBy('amount', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

I am retrieving the values from $s1 variable through loop.

Following is the output:

[image]

and i want the result like this:

[image]

Please click on the links given above. I am new to this forum so its not allowing me to add images in the question. Kindly help.

Here is the entire code:

```
  if($s1 != null)
```

{

```
echo "<div class='panel-body'>";
    echo "<table class='table table-responsive'>"; $c = 1;
    echo "<th>Drama Title</th>";
    echo "<th>Show Date</th>";
    echo "<th>Seat booked</th>";
    echo "<th>Amount</th>";
    echo "<th>User</th>";


    for($i=0;$i<count($s1);$i++)
    {



        echo "<tr><td>".$shows1[0]->show_title."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$shows[0]->show_date."</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $s1[$i]->selected_seats; 
        echo "</td>";
        /*echo $s1[$i]->userid."<br/>";
        echo $s1[$i]->amount."<br/>";*/

        $transactions = DB::table('transactions')->where('userid',$s1[$i]->userid)->where('show_id',$s1[$i]->show_id)->get();
        //var_dump($transactions);
        $total_amount = 0;
        //echo "<pre>Users<br/>"; var_dump($transactions);

        foreach ($transactions as $transaction)
        {
            //echo "userid&nbsp;".$s1[$i]->userid."&nbsp;"."show id:&nbsp;".$transaction->show_id."&nbsp;&nbsp;"."<br/>";
           // echo "amount:&nbsp;".$transaction->amount."&nbsp;";
            $amount = $transaction->amount;
            $total_amount = $total_amount + $amount; //echo $amount."<br/>";
            $c = $c+1;
            //echo "no. of seats:".$c;
            $users = DB::table('users')->where('id',$s1[$i]->userid)->get();

        } 
        echo "<td>".$total_amount."</td>";

        //echo $s1[$i]->userid."<br/>";
        //echo "<td>".$users[0]->name."</td>";
        //echo "<pre>"; var_dump($users);
        echo "</td>";
        if(isset($users[0]))
        {
            //echo "values are set"; 
            echo "<td>".$users[0]->name."</td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            //echo "null value"; 
            continue;
        }

    }   




    /*echo $shows[0]->show_date."<br/>";
    echo $shows[0]->show_title;*/
    //echo "<pre>"; var_dump($s1);
    //echo "<td>".$users[0]->name."</td>";
    //echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

}
else
{
  echo "No records found";

}

Comment: If You want your table to look like the 2nd screen-shot, then you are missing some fields in your Query. For example, I didn't see the E-Mail ID Field in your Query nor the Customer/User Name (although they appeared in the 1st Screen-Shot). Can you show us your the Structure of the Table: transactions? Just the Definition would be enough or the Fields it contains?

Comment: Try `->groupBy(DB::raw('amount WITH ROLLUP'))`

Comment: You can try using jqgrid. Its a great plugin to render data in grids with many more functionalities. If you usuallu use tables, you will be in love with jqgrid. I found this plugin as a fortune.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I think is calculate amounts in the loop you are printing data or readying data to send to a view. Since your data sorted by user_id, you always can change amount variable in the loop when user_id is changing. You can use `count(explode($seat_variable))` to get number of seats in a single run of the loop. Look at the example code below.

`$num_seat = 0; $amount = 0; $running_user_id = -1;
foreach ($row as $entry) {
    ...
    if ($running_user_id != $entry['user_id']) { // check if the same user
        $running_user_id = $entry['user_id']; 
        $num_seat = 0; $amount = 0; // resetting variable values for seperate user.
    }
    $num_seat += count(explode($entry['selected_seats']));
    $amount += $entry['amount'];
    ...
}`

And I assume you have missing data like emails in the query.

**Code update after questioner added his code.**

```
if($s1 != null) {
    echo "<div class='panel-body'>";
    echo "<table class='table table-responsive'>"; $c = 1;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Drama Title</th>";
    echo "<th>Show Date</th>";
    echo "<th>Seat booked</th>";
    echo "<th>Amount</th>";
    // echo "<th>User</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

$category = ""; $num_seats = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<count($s1); $i++) {
    if ($category != $amount) { 
        if ($i > 0) { // print totals 
            echo "<tr>
            <td colspan='3' align='right'>Total</td>
            <td>".$num_seats."</td>
            <td>".($num_seats * $amount)."</td>
        </tr>";

            echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>&nbsp;</td></tr>"; // empty row after totals printed
            $num_seats = 0; //resetting number of seats per category
        }
        echo "<tr><td colspan='5'><h2>Category : ".$amount."</h2></td></tr>"; // printing category line in the given table
        $category = $amount; // this logic is to prevent category line printing for each row
    }
    $transactions = DB::table('transactions')->where('userid',$s1[$i]->userid)->where('show_id',$s1[$i]->show_id)->get();
    echo "<tr>";

    $users = DB::table('users')->where('id', $s1[$i]->userid)->get();
    // Check below values are correct or not
    echo "<td>".$users[0]->name."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$s1[$i]->userid."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$s1[$i]->email."</td>"; // get user's email property here
    echo "<td>".$s1[$i]->selected_seats."</td>";

    $num_seats += count(explode(',', $s1[$i]->selected_seats));
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td></tr>"; // empty colomn for amount and the row end
}
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: I have already sorted the data according to userid. Now i want to sort the rows as shown in image2. I have tried your code but its output is similar to my previous output.

Comment: You can't directly use my code. Post your code in your question. So I may can help more.

Comment: Check my edit in the answer. Please make sure all variables (user->email) are correct. I formatted the result printing exactly same as the output you wanted. I didn't check HTML formatting.